# Dynamically highlighting a data point using button_press_event or motion_notify_event in matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to dynamically print the data point that has been selected by clicking. To do this I used button_press_event of matplotlib.pyplot; the code below works fine when I set the title with event.xdata and event.ydata, but when I am trying to set the title with data[np.rint(event.xdata)] it stops working. I am trying to display the original x and y value from data[], as my data is continuous rounding of event.xdata give me the correct index of data[]

```
%matplotlib notebook
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
data = np.random.rand(10)
plt.plot(data)

def onclick(event):
    plt.cla()
    plt.plot(data)
    x = np.rint(event.xdata)
    plt.gca().set_title('data at {} = {}'.format(x, event.ydata))
    #plt.gca().set_title('data at {} = {}'.format(x, data[x]))

plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick);
```

Can someone please tell me why below line is not working?

```
plt.gca().set_title('data at {} = {}'.format(x, data[x]))
```

I am using python 3 and jupyter notebook.

Comment: Consider that `x` needs to be an integer between 0 and 9 in order for `data[x]` to work. `x = int(np.rint(event.xdata))`.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked!! The return value of np.rint() was of type numpy.float64.

Answer (score 0):

Now that the above code worked I tried to highlight the point closest to the cursor. To do so I changed the function def onclick(event) as follows:

```
def onclick(event):
   plt.cla()
   plt.plot(data)
   x = int(np.rint(event.xdata))
   plt.gca().set_title('data at {} = {}'.format(x, data[x]))
   plt.plot(x,data[x],'o')
   fig.canvas.draw()
```

This worked perfectly. [This is how it looks!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyRdA.png)

The above code still works on click, so tried to change it to mouse motion.

```
def on_motion(event):
    x = int(np.rint(event.xdata))
    if x < 0:
        x = 0
    plt.gca().set_title('data at {} = {}'.format(x, data[x]))
    plt.plot(x,data[x],'ro')
    plt.draw()

plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event',on_motion);
```

While moving the mouse this is creating multiple red dots. Looks like it is not redrawing properly. [Here is the image with multiple red dots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1R3sm.png)

Can someone please help!!

Comment: Missed to add the below lines at the start of on_motion() function. 
    plt.cla()
    plt.plot(data)

Comment: However, this process is slow once you have many data points (> 5000). Also when I increased the number of data points, it became impossible to select the point I was interested in.

To understand the pain, use: data = np.random.gamma(2, 1.5, 20000)

Answer (score 0):

The problem now changed from identifying a particular point to displaying the points such that they can be seen distinctly. Especially when the number of data points are in Millions. To do that I used 3 windows:

- A window showing the complete data with million plus data points and having a rectangle data selection box.
- A 2nd window showing the data selected using the above rectangle. Additionally, the second window has its own rectangle data selection box.
- A 3rd window showing the data selected using the above rectangle.

The code is a hybrid of below codes:

- https://matplotlib.org/gallery/event_handling/zoom_window.html
- Draggable rectangle exercise from https://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html

Now in the 3rd window I can select an individual data point and show its details. Click this link to see how this [3 window zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AANxV.png) solution looks. The code is too big, but sharing some important parts:

```
class DraggableRectangle:
def __init__(self, rect, data, zoomWidth, src, zoom, otherRect = None, otherZoomWiidth = 0, moreZoom = None):
    self.rect = rect
    self.data = data
    #Primary window details
    self.zoomWidth = zoomWidth
    self.axsrc  = src 
    self.axzoom = zoom
    #Secondary optional window details
    self.otherRect = otherRect
    self.otherZoomWiidth = otherZoomWiidth
    self.axMoreZoom = moreZoom

def connect(self):
    #connect to all the events we need
    self.cidpress = self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_connect(
        'button_press_event', self.on_press)

def on_press(self, event):
    #on button press we will see if the mouse is over the desired window
    if event.inaxes == self.axsrc: 
        x = int(np.rint(event.xdata))
        # Restricting the window to go beyond the lowest point 
        if x - (self.zoomWidth/2) < 0:
            x = 0
        else: 
            # (x - zoomWidth/2) is used to make the point of click the center of the box
            x = int(x - (self.zoomWidth/2))
        self.rect.set_x(x)
        self.zoomStart = x
        self.axzoom.set_xlim(x , x + self.zoomWidth)
        self.axzoom.set_ylim(float(self.data[x:x+self.zoomWidth].min()-0.5), 
                             float(self.data[x:x+self.zoomWidth].max()+0.5) )
        if self.otherRect == None or self.otherZoomWiidth == 0:
            self.rect.figure.canvas.draw()
        else: #If second window is present
            self.otherRect.set_x(x)
            self.otherRect.set_height(self.data[x:x+self.zoomWidth].max()+0.5)
            self.axMoreZoom.set_xlim(x , x + self.zoomWidth)
            self.axMoreZoom.set_ylim(float(self.data[x:x+self.otherZoomWiidth].min()-0.5), 
                             float(self.data[x:x+self.otherZoomWiidth].max()+0.5) )
            self.rect.figure.canvas.draw()

def disconnect(self):
    #disconnect all the stored connection ids
    self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cidpress)
```

Now the main code with the imports, here one can adjust the zoom width. My plot is for 1.6 Million data points:

```
%matplotlib notebook
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
from matplotlib import gridspec

data = np.random.gamma(2, 2, 1600000)
zoomWidth_1 = 15000
zoomWidth_2 = int(zoomWidth_1 / 12)
```

While drawing the window one need to take care of xlim and ylim as we are zooming based on those values.

```
allData = plt.subplot(gs[0])
allData.set(title='All Data window')
plt.plot(data, alpha=0.5)
plt.gcf().canvas.draw()

# Zoom Window
slicedData_1 = plt.subplot(gs[1])
slicedData_1.set(xlim=(0, zoomWidth_1), 
                   ylim=(float(data[0:zoomWidth_1].min()-0.5), float(data[0:zoomWidth_1].max()+0.5)), 
                   autoscale_on=False,
                   title='Zoom window')
plt.plot(data, alpha=0.5)
plt.gcf().canvas.draw()

# More Zoom window
slicedData_2 = plt.subplot(gs[2])
slicedData_2.set(xlim=(0, zoomWidth_2), 
                   ylim=(float(data[0:zoomWidth_2].min()-0.5), float(data[0:zoomWidth_2].max()+0.5)), 
                   autoscale_on=False,
                   title='More Zoom window')
plt.plot(data, alpha=0.6)
plt.gcf().canvas.draw()
```

Lastly the rectangle creation:

```
#Rectangle in Zoom window
slicedData_1 = plt.subplot(gs[1])
rect_2 = Rectangle((0,-0.2),zoomWidth_2,data[0:zoomWidth_1].max()+0.5,
                linewidth=2,edgecolor='r',facecolor='none', alpha=0.7)
dr_2 = DraggableRectangle(rect_2, data, zoomWidth_2, slicedData_1, slicedData_2)
plt.gca().add_patch(rect_2)
dr_2.connect()

#Rectangle in allData window; should also adjust the rectangle in zoom Window
allData = plt.subplot(gs[0])
rect_1 = Rectangle((0,-0.2),zoomWidth_1,data.max()+0.5,
                    linewidth=2,edgecolor='r',facecolor='none', alpha=0.7)
dr_1 = DraggableRectangle(rect_1, data, zoomWidth_1, allData, slicedData_1, rect_2, zoomWidth_2, slicedData_2)
plt.gca().add_patch(rect_1)
dr_1.connect()
```